# Cannot set as default new file geodatabase in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, esri-geodatabase, default

I 'm trying to set as default a newly created geodatabase but I'm not finding the option in the menu box.

Can anyone help me?

[image]Sorry, but  I cannot find it...

Comment: That's not ArcMap you are showing that's ArcCatalog. The concept of a default geodatabase applies to a MXD (map document) only. You are looking at the wrong application!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because poster is asking about functionality that is in a completely different application.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions for [Setting the default geodatabase](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-arcmap/working-with-the-home-folder-and-default-geodatabase.htm#:%7E:text=Setting%20the%20default%20geodatabase&text=Navigate%20to%20the%20desired%20geodatabase,and%20click%20Make%20Default%20Geodatabase.) of a map in ArcMap can be found in its Online Help:

> 1. Ensure that you have access. If necessary, for an enterprise geodatabase, establish a database connection. If you want to create a
>    new file geodatabase, you can use the **Catalog** window to create a
>    new geodatabase that will be your map's default.
> 2. Navigate to the desired geodatabase in the tree view and click to highlight it. Right-click the geodatabase to see its context menu and
>    click **Make Default Geodatabase**.